# How to create a scrollable div with fixed div on it's right and make both divs scrollable when the scrollable div reaches the end

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create something like this:

https://www.gymshark.com/products/gymshark-vital-seamless-2-0-light-t-shirt-chilli-red-marl-ss22

You see, when on desktop you scroll down, the product details on right stay fixed while the images on the left scroll down until they reach the end and then the product details get scrolled as well.

Can you please tell me how can I create this effect with HTML, CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: are you doing it in vanilla js or react type frameworks ?

Comment: @AmirRahman Just vanilla js.

Comment: i have checked the code in dev tool i dont see any change from js its very tricky maybe its happening with css only i am not sure i am still checking that page to find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its all happening with css

```
position : sticky;
top : 0
```

here in this example left div is 200vh and right is 100vh
so applying those two css to shorter div will keep it sticky while scrolling for the rest of the container and then as soon as container reach the end it will start scoll again

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Experiment</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header p-5 bg-green-500 text-white text-2xl text-center">this is header</div>
    <div class="scrollBody flex items-start">
        <div class="each overflow-hidden p-5 w-[70%] h-[200vh] bg-green-200">
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, nam assumenda numquam corporis repellendus
            rem esse itaque non vitae molestias aperiam ratione debitis quas hic sit iste quos dolore quo.
            Alias a veritatis repellat tenetur quo dolore voluptas, odit porro iure eum quia error quisquam quas
            delectus quibusdam totam velit sapiente similique quidem ex omnis exercitationem. Ratione minima architecto
            sint.
            Ipsum quibusdam rerum architecto asperiores itaque, maiores corrupti. Doloremque inventore, totam aliquam
            unde reprehenderit eos! Cupiditate deleniti voluptatum fuga totam vero, nulla a provident quam illum quas
            tempore impedit error.
            Nostrum sapiente veritatis consequatur exercitationem. Veniam accusantium dolor facilis ad quis sequi ullam
            aut unde blanditiis rem velit doloremque ducimus, voluptatibus consequuntur delectus, laboriosam possimus
            quas. Eligendi accusantium reprehenderit porro!
            Optio, eveniet! Qui quos tempora dolorem nihil, odit, perferendis laborum distinctio, id illo magni eaque
            labore corporis accusamus placeat quam aspernatur doloremque. Eaque accusantium maiores suscipit voluptatum
            expedita perspiciatis architecto!
            Sed laudantium modi fugit numquam dolorum repellendus, ex veniam saepe iure nobis! Animi tempore quo nulla,
            eveniet, architecto voluptatum, odio dignissimos temporibus molestias et sit. Dolor, illo. Recusandae, magni
            exercitationem.
            Autem quaerat soluta voluptatum quibusdam quas incidunt ducimus accusamus dolorum sed tempore nesciunt a
            possimus nostrum ullam delectus dolore consequuntur fugit voluptatem aspernatur, numquam rerum dignissimos
            quasi aliquid quae! Aliquid.
        </div>
        <div class="each overflow-hidden p-5 w-[30%] h-[100vh] bg-green-400 sticky top-0">
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto pariatur ratione voluptates porro, nemo
            aut cumque, aliquam assumenda libero placeat laboriosam modi harum doloremque ullam labore voluptatum? Et,
            nam saepe.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="each overflow-hidden p-5 w-[100%] h-[200vh] bg-purple-500">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, nam assumenda numquam corporis repellendus rem
        esse itaque non vitae molestias aperiam ratione debitis quas hic sit iste quos dolore quo.
        Alias a veritatis repellat tenetur quo dolore voluptas, odit porro iure eum quia error quisquam quas delectus
        quibusdam totam velit sapiente similique quidem ex omnis exercitationem. Ratione minima architecto sint.
        Ipsum quibusdam rerum architecto asperiores itaque, maiores corrupti. Doloremque inventore, totam aliquam unde
        reprehenderit eos! Cupiditate deleniti voluptatum fuga totam vero, nulla a provident quam illum quas tempore
        impedit error.
        Nostrum sapiente veritatis consequatur exercitationem. Veniam accusantium dolor facilis ad quis sequi ullam aut
        unde blanditiis rem velit doloremque ducimus, voluptatibus consequuntur delectus, laboriosam possimus quas.
        Eligendi accusantium reprehenderit porro!
        Optio, eveniet! Qui quos tempora dolorem nihil, odit, perferendis laborum distinctio, id illo magni eaque labore
        corporis accusamus placeat quam aspernatur doloremque. Eaque accusantium maiores suscipit voluptatum expedita
        perspiciatis architecto!
        Sed laudantium modi fugit numquam dolorum repellendus, ex veniam saepe iure nobis! Animi tempore quo nulla,
        eveniet, architecto voluptatum, odio dignissimos temporibus molestias et sit. Dolor, illo. Recusandae, magni
        exercitationem.
        Autem quaerat soluta voluptatum quibusdam quas incidunt ducimus accusamus dolorum sed tempore nesciunt a
        possimus nostrum ullam delectus dolore consequuntur fugit voluptatem aspernatur, numquam rerum dignissimos quasi
        aliquid quae! Aliquid.
    </div>
</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

</html>
```